# How to say/play the whisper/greeting message on the called party's end, after called party answers, but before the parties are connected

Tags: c#, twilio

In our application, users call on twilios numbers of our website. When users call on twilios number an event is triggered. I wrote this event in C# language:

```
public void RaiseCallEvent()
{
    NumberGroupsService _NumberGroupService = new NumberGroupsService();
    string CallerTo = Request.QueryString["To"];//This is a caller number
    string From = Request.QueryString["From"];// This is the called party number
    string AccountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAccountSid"];
    string AuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAuthToken"];
    Twilio.TwiML.TwilioResponse response = new Twilio.TwiML.TwilioResponse();
    string RecordingPath = ServerUrl + "/content/RecordingFiles/" + _NumberGroup.RecordingFile;
    response.Say("Welcome user");//This is a whisper message
    response.Play(RecordingPath);
}
```

In this function i am getting caller number and called party's number. The greeting message is working on the caller number but i want to say/play the whisper/greeting message on the called party's end, after called party answers, but before the parties are connected.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

To add a whisper to the dialed party's leg of your phone call you can use the Number TwiML verbs [`url`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url) attribute.  To set that using the TwiML helper library, you can call the `Dial` method, passing in the phone number you want to dial, null for the `<Dial>` verbs attributes and then an anonymous type containing the url property for the `<Number>` nouns attributes:

```
response.Dial("+15555555555", null, new { url="http://example.com/whisper" });
```

This shuld output TwiML that looks like this:

```
<Dial>
    <Number url="http://example.com/whisper" />
</Dial>
```

The `/Whisper` route can return TwiML containing the `<Say>` or `<Play>` you want the dialed party to hear.

Hope that helps.

Comment: the first answer does not work anymore. What is the updated version? The docs mention using 'Client', but as soon as I append the client attribute to my dial, the call just hangs up.